# Creating, Accessing and understanding multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have implemented the following small example:

```
$nodeList;  
for($i = 0; $i < 10;$i++) {
    $nodeList[$i] = $i;
    for($j = 0; $j < 3;$j++) {
        $nodeList[$i][$j] = $j;
    }
}

foreach($nodeList[0] as $nodeEl) {
    print "NodeEl: ".$nodeEl." | ";
}

print nl2br("\n\r");

$testList = array
  (
  array(1,2,3),
  array(4,5,6),
  array(7,8,9),
  array(10,11,12),
  );
foreach($testList[0] as $testEl) {
    print "TestEl: ".$testEl." | ";
}
```

Where the output for `$nodeList` is `null` (var_dump / print_r too) and the output for `$testList` is `TestEl: 1 | TestEl: 2 | TestEl: 3`, as expected.

In my understanding those two solutions should create roughly the same output - but instead there is no output for the first one at all. Because the second dimension of the array is not even created.

Reading up on http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php creates the strong feeling that the [] operator is only for *dereferencing / accessing* of the array, but then again the docs provide a sample where they assign a value to a certain key the same way I do `$arr["x"] = 42`.

What is the difference between these two ways of array access?

How can I achieve filling a n-dimensional array in a way similar to the way I try to fill `$nodeList`?

Comment: Why do you assign `$i`  to `$nodeList[$i]`? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @trincot: I want to resemble a topology. Imagine I have objects with the ID 1.2 and 1.3 and an object with ID 1. I want to store object 1 at position 1 in $nodeList[1], object 1.2 on the position $nodeList[1][2] and 1.3 at $nodeList[1][3]. I somewhat forgot that the value of $nodeList[$i] will point to the next array, and won't provide a value itself... Quite embarrassing.

Comment: I see, well you could make your arrays to contain more than just the nested array, by giving them a property for a direct value (or object), and another property for the nested array.

Comment: @trincot: That seems like a nice way to go. I already implemented the same thing as a tree (which is more intuitive anyways) - but wanted to see how it works out as arrays (as PHP seems quite flexible in that way). Thanks for your quick and detailed reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure to have error reporting turned on, because warnings are generated for your code:

```
E_WARNING :  type 2 -- Cannot use a scalar value as an array -- at line 7
```

This concerns the following statement:

```
$nodeList[$i] = $i;
```

If you want to create a 2D array, there is no meaning in assigning a number on the first level. Instead you want `$nodeList[$i]` to be an array. PHP does that implicitely (creating the array) when you access it with brackets `[...]`, so you can just leave out the offending statement, and do:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10;$i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 3;$j++) {
        $nodeList[$i][$j] = $j;
    }
}
```

You can even leave out the `$j` in the last bracket pair, which means PHP will just add to the array using the next available numerical index:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10;$i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 3;$j++) {
        $nodeList[$i][] = $j;
    }
}
```

#### Adding a value at every level

If you really need to store `$i` at the first level of the 2D array, then consider using a more complex structure where each element is an associative array with two keys: one for the value and another for the nested array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $nodeList[$i] = array(
        "value" => $i,
        "children" => array()
    );
    for($j = 0; $j < 3;$j++) {
        $nodeList[$i]["children"][] = array(
            "value" => "$i.$j" // just example of value, could be just $j
        );
    }
}
```

`$nodeList` will be like this then:

```
array (
  array (
    'value' => 0,
    'children' => array (
      array ('value' => '0.0'),
      array ('value' => '0.1'),
      array ('value' => '0.2'),
    ),
  ),
  array (
    'value' => 1,
    'children' => array (
      array ('value' => '1.0'),
      array ('value' => '1.1'),
      array ('value' => '1.2'),
    ),
  ),
  //...etc
);
```

Comment: This seems the way to go if one wants to use arrays for this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
<?php

$nodeList;  
for($i = 0; $i < 10;$i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 3;$j++) {
        $nodeList[$i][$j] = $j;
    }
}

foreach($nodeList[0] as $nodeEl) {
    print "NodeEl: ".$nodeEl." | ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `$nodeList` as array like

```
$nodeList=array();
```

and for 2D array

```
$nodeList= array(array());
```

Comment: I tried and - sadly - it doesn't change a thing.
The documentation states: As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []. 
Also I think the creation of the array happens on the fly anyways.

Comment: As noted by @bouquet-lucy in another answer your for loop is also wrong